# Linux System Parameters to Increase CPU utilization [Reduce page faults, context switches]

Tags: linux, centos, operating-system, cpu, cpu-usage

I am running my program on OS version `centos-release-7-1.1503.el7.centos.2.8.x86_64`. Following are observations I have recorded using SAR stats,

CPU Utilization(60-70%) :
[image: CPU Utilization During Program Run]

I am suspecting following might be parameters causing low system utilization 
Faults per Sec :
[image: Paging]

Context Switches Per Second :
[image: Processes]

What might be parameter limiting CPU performance? What system parameters can be set to improve this performance?

Comment: Absolutely impossible to answer without much more detail on what your program is actually doing.

Comment: @duskwuff it is sar recording during loading data in memory using [Apache  Ignite framework](https://ignite.apache.org/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)